# How to upgrade my login shell from bash version 3 to 4?

Tags: bash, command-line

Current I am running

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
$ 3.2.57(1)-release
```

I have the new shell in

```
/usr/local/bin/bash
```

and I can run it directly with

```
/usr/local/bin/bash
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
$ 4.3.42(1)-release
```

I have done

```
$ chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to fully quit the terminal application in order for the changes to take effect.  osx is different in this way as it leaves applications 'open' even when all current window occurrences of it are closed.

Comment: Did you add `/usr/local/bin/bash` to `/private/etc/shells`?

Comment: I did not.  Did not need to.

Comment: I don't think you can expect different behavior on any other U*x.